# How can I ask for input again and again and not let the program break?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code and I want `game=input('> ')` again and again

```
import json

game = input('> ')

def get_bank_data():
    with open ("mainbank.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    return users

def open_account():
    users = get_bank_data()

    if int in users:
        return False

    else:
        users = {}
        users["wallet"] = 0
        users["bank"] = 0

    with open ("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
    return True

if game.lower() == 'balance':
    open_account()
    users = get_bank_data()

    wallet_amt = users["wallet"]
    bank_amt = users["bank"]

    print(f'''Wallet: {wallet_amt}
    Bank: {bank_amt}''')
```

Comment: Do research into while loops. Hint: `while(True)`

Answer (score 2):

```
import json

while True:
    game = input(‘> ‘)
    
    ...
```

This would set game = input(‘> ‘) each iteration of the loop.